# In what cases is it better to use message queues instead of Twitter Storm

Tags: message-queue, apache-storm

I'm reading up on Twitter Storm, and it seems like it provides a higher level of abstraction over message queues for building data pipelines. I'm wondering what situations there are (if any), where it would be preferable to work 'bare metal' with the message queues directly, rather than Storm.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Storm isn't tied to messages queues. Properly you are seeing a lot of use cases of Apache Storm and Apache Kafka but that is because they work together very nicely.
The input source to Storm could be a lot of things. It could be Apache Cassandra, MongoDB, Twitter feed, sensors, TCP connection, etc.

Use case of not using Storm is when, well you don't need its capabilities.
Lets say in your system, when an article goes out of stock, you need to update the DB and inform the purchasing team. You only need a message queue here and you don't need Storm for that.

Good use cases for Storm is personalisation, recommendation, sorting, outbreak detection, etc.